# Is there a way to show numeric keypad of android but with only selected numbers?

Tags: android

Is there a way to show numeric keypad of android but with only selected numbers?

Like i want to only show the numbers 2,4,6,8..all other numbers and signs should be blocked.

is there a way to do that in android?

Comment: You need to create the Custom keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Not really. I believe that you have the following options:

1. Create a custom keyboard

The most important downside is that each of your users would have to select your keyboard from system settings as the default.

2. Create a view, which looks like a keyboard

Probably the best approach, but the 'keyboard' most likely won't look like the native one.

3. Handle only the desired keys and ignore other.

If you can show all buttons and handle only a few of them - do that.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs, there is a XML Attribute that should do the trick, but I have not tested it:

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/yourEditTextId"
android:digits="2468"
android:inputType="number" />
```

The XML Attribute `digits`, which is inherited from `TextView`, is described as follows:

***If set, specifies that this TextView has a numeric input method and that these specific characters are the ones that it will accept. If this is set, numeric is implied to be true. The default is false.***

Comment: Actually i am using a library for my preference screen and the edittextpreference creates when after the xml parsing is complete (when the dialog for that is invoked) thats why attributes in xml wont work for me..if u can suggest any other way please tell me..

Comment: can you please edit your post, show the code you have and name the library you are using.